# Variable While Loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I would like to know how to include -, *, and ,/, in the following while loop in addition to the + I have already included. If the user enters something other than +, -, * or / I want the invalid input message to print. However, so far I have only worked out how to include one of the arguments in the code, in this case the +. How do I include the other 3 arguments in the same bit of code? I am a noobie I admit, and I don't currently have the vocabulary to search an answer specific to my needs so thought my best best was writing out the issue. 
Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
echo "Please enter an operation of arithmetic. Press either +, -, * or /"

read operation
while [ $operation != "+" ]; do

echo "sorry, that is an invalid input- re-enter operation of arithmatic"
read operation
```

Comment: The search vocabulary term you're missing is "conditional". Try searching for bash+conditional.

Comment: Look at the `select` command for choosing a value from a list of options.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes conditional is what I was after, I'll remember that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that in a `while` loop like this:

```
while read -p "Please enter an operation of arithmetic. Press either +, -, * or /: " op &&
     [[ $op != [-+/*] ]]; do
   echo "sorry, that is an invalid input- re-enter operation of arithmatic"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `select` here:

```
PS3="Please enter an operation of arithmetic: "
select op in + - / '*'; do
    case $op in 
        -) echo subtract something ; break ;;
        +) echo add something ; break ;;
        /) echo divide something ; break ;;
       \*) echo multiply something ; break ;;
    esac
done
```